# Change text displayed when cart is empty

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I'm using Drupal 7 with Commerce and I'd like to change the text shown when the user visits `/cart` and they have not added any items, from the default "Your shopping cart is empty." to a custom message, preferably that contains HTML.

I have tried adding custom text under no results behavior commerce_cart_form view with no luck.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a theme function called `commerce_cart_empty_page` is used. So you should be able to add a function:
`MYTHEME_commerce_cart_empty_page()`
to your themes template.php file and return whatever html you want.

You can also do the same for the cart block with a theme function `MYTHEME_commerce_cart_empty_block()`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: This works like magic.. Likes :)